# FCM Notification not appearing when it send through CURL command line

Tags: android, curl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Request:

```
curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=server key"  -X POST -d 
'{ "to": "/topics/all","priorty": "HIGH","data": { "message": "This is a Firebase"}}'
```

URL:https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Response from FCM:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
> Date: Tue, 02 May 2017 04:46:09 GMT
> Expires: Tue, 02 May 2017 04:46:09 GMT
> Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> Server: GSE
> Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"
> Accept-Ranges: none
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that FCM replied correctly is a good sign. I think the problem with it is that your 'priority' field has a typo(priorty) that's why the actual priority was not set to high. So your actual notification is not received since it may be delayed, lost, etc.

Can you double check? I might suggest using a tool like POSTMan instead of CURL.

Comment: some edit in my answer, sorry for being lazy and generalizing but truth is  some notifications are not really reliable and yes it is not due to priority but setting it to high makes it more 'reliable' since FCM sned the message to the user without delay. :)

Comment: when i try using postman, i got something like this. i don't know why? JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.